# Left Windows Key shortcuts don't work in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

About a week ago, I have noticed something unusual on my Windows 10. When I am logged in, left Windows key does not work, same with Win+R, Win+E, etc. Instead, left Alt works now like a Windows key, so when I want to open Run window, I need to press Right Win + R or Left Alt + R, which is very irritating.

I connected the keyboard to another computer and everything works here.

Does anybody had any ideas? I am not using any keyboard remapping software.

Comment: Sounds like you have a different keyboard layout.  I would make sure the keyboard settings are set to the same as a week ago.

Comment: I use "Polish (programmers)" keyboard layout and it is my only keyboard layout at the moment.